# Howto ignore/catch Doctrine "convert database value error"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using `Doctrine` within a `Symfony 2.8` project. One of the entities uses an array field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="raw_data", type="array", nullable=true)
 */
protected $data;
```

Due to a bug some entities stored a string within this property instead of an array:

```
$entity->setData('some string');
// ==> DB value: s:11:"some string";
```

Persisting the entities did not caused any problem. However, when trying to load the entity from the DB Doctrine throws an error:

> Could not convert database value "s:11:"some str..." to Doctrine Type array

This makes sense, since the value does not represent an array.

Of course I could manipulate the DB manually, search for all values which do not start with `a:....` and fix or replace them.

**But is there a way to tell Doctrine to automatically ignore such error and return an empty array instead?**

Answer (score 0):

I would fix it with an handcrafted migration script
to keep the code clean of any "workarounds" for bugs made earlier.

Use doctrine/migrations-bundle if you are not already. It makes life easy.

Then generate a new migration class with `bin/console mig:mig:gen`
and there use can use plain sql to fix the values. (reserialise after building an array)

You can even access the container from the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any better way but to me it seems like you need a hack to get over this problem. In your case, I would get all your entities as arrays using `$query->getArrayResult();` instead of `$query->getResult();`. Then find which entities have wrongly formed data field and delete them through querybuilder `delete()` function.

So you could get your code working again and then add some validation so that this will not occur again.